# How to interpret the Cointegration test result?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, cointegration, eviews

[image]

[image]

How to interpret the Cointegration result?

Comment: Hi @Shi Hui. There are two different test stats. The trace stat, and the max eigen stat. Both of which are interpreted sequently according to respective p-values. As an example, lets take the trace stat from the top down: "we reject the null hypothesis that there are no cointegrated vectors" and so on.... In other words, there exists one long-run relationship in your model.

Comment: There trace + max eigen are often found to tell slightly different stories. But I think when they mismatch, the trace stat is argued to be sovereign. This needs a little more investigation by yourself.